# matplotlib not working anymore due to interactive issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was working with python and matplotlib but my script crashed so I had to turn off the terminal (Ubuntu 12.04, matplotib-1.1.0, python2.7).
Now if I try to run any script it crashes on the line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 32, in <module>
    import new
  File "/home/federico/Documents/doc_uni/idraulica_ambientale/relazione/scripts/variabili/new.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
ImportError: cannot import name interactive
```

Notice the last line.
I tried removing and reinstalling matplotlib both from source and from pip and easy_install but I can't get away with it. Same error happens if I try to import from within the python interpreter.
I also installed version 1.2.0 to see if that work but it does not.

Comment: You say you have matplotlib 1.1.0, but the error messages refer to 1.2.0.  Do you have multiple versions installed somehow?

Comment: I forgot to say that. I couldn't solve the problem so I tried installing version 1.2.0. I don't know if I messed up doing it but it didn't work with the previous too.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off the terminal"?

Comment: by turn of the terminal I mean killing bash while the process of my python script was still running (but freezed)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` and then give your script another shot.

Comment: Already did that. Didn't fix it. Inside my matplotlib dir into my site-packages I haven't got any file called interactive.py although I have _pylab_helpers.py in fact.

Comment: for reference, `interactive` is a function defined in `__init__.py`.

Comment: There is something oddly circular going on here....

Comment: Try this, it worked for me! :
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/41796619/2066052](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41796619/2066052)

Comment: I have found the answer. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41796619/2066052

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read through files in the stack trace,

`new.py`-> `/matplotlib/__init__.py` -> `matplotlib/rcsetup.py`, `/matplotlib/colors.py` -> `/matplotlib/cbook.py` --> **/home/federico/Documents/../new.py** -> `matplotlib/pyplot.py`

You have named your module `new` which is shadowing with an import in `matplolib.cbook`, which is causing you to try to imort `pyplot` while you are importing `pyplot` which aparently blows up (exactly *why* is above my paygrade).  You just need to re-name your module to something other than `new.py` (and remember to remove the `new.pyc` file that got created).

As a test run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in an interactive shell.

FYI [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/new.html) is what you are shadowing.

This import will be removed in mpl 1.3

Comment: you are right, sorry for the mess. Anyway, when running `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` from within the ipython shell I get the message /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
  set_interactive(1)

Comment: @fmonegaglia that looks like dependency issues.  If you think my answer answered the question you asked, you should accept it and then open a new question with the details of the new issue.

Comment: also make sure the current directory in the interactive shell is not one where you have any modules defined and you have not added anything to your python path.

Comment: Also ensure that the new.pyc file is deleted as well