# Suddenly, I can't run any project. Python/Eclipse [error]

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

I was working on my code, and suddenly I've started getting this error. I've tried to run another projects - the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 549, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 538, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 463, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    _aliases = aliases.aliases
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'aliases'
```

EDIT: I tried to switch workspace and create a new PyDev project, but I cant create the project because there is no interpreter choice.

Comment: Did you happen to name one of your files `aliases.py`?

Comment: Did you uninstall python? Do you have a local file called 'aliases.py' that might be shadowing the system one?

Comment: Let's see your code. Are you sure you imported the _class_ and not just the module?

Comment: possible related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130527/matplotlib-not-working-anymore-due-to-interactive-issue/14132653#14132653

Comment: @JustinJasmann I havent imported anything, I was just trying my Flask web app. :/

Comment: Odd... `aliases` comes from `from encodings import aliases`, and we can see from the traceback that nothing is shadowing `encodings`, so I don't see why `aliases.aliases` would fail.

Comment: Did you edit anything in the `C:\Python27` directory hierarchy? It looks like something may have messed with `encodings.aliases`.

Comment: @user2357112 No, I did not. Its weird. It happend after I tried to run flask app with attribute. run app(debug=True) But I guess its not the point... But who knows..

Comment: Thanks for interest guys.. I tried to reinstall Python 2.7.6. It helped.