# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror, canopy

I am trying to run a simple code and I have all the dependencies for matplotlib and numpy installed in my Canopy. Still I am getting error.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = cv2.imread('jay.jpg')
    plt.imshow(x, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
    plt.show()
```

Error:

```
     %run "c:\users\jay\appdata\local\temp\tmppvibq9.py"
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     c:\users\jay\appdata\local\temp\tmppvibq9.py in <module>()
     2 import numpy as np
     3 import matplotlib.cbook
     ----> 4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     5 
     6 x = cv2.imread('jay.jpg')

     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     27 from cycler import cycler
     28 import matplotlib
     ---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
     30 from matplotlib import style
     31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import matplotlib as mpl
     ---> 32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     34 import matplotlib.collections as collections

     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <module>()
     9 import numpy as np
     10 import matplotlib
     ---> 11 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     12 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation
     13 from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams

     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'
```

Dependencies I have installed for numpy and matplotlib:
1.) libsvm-3.17.win64-py2.7
2.) pyparsing-2.0.3-1.win64-py2.7
3.) python-dateutil-2.4.2-2.win64-py2.7
4.) pytz-2015.7-1.win64-py2.7
5.) six-1.10.0-1.win64-py2.7
6.) scipy-0.13.3.win64-py2.7
7.) numpy-MKL-1.9.2-2.win64-py2.7
8.) Matplotlib 1.5.1-win64-py2.7
9.) pip 8.0.2-1.win64-py2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure that this is causing your problem, but you are running your code in the wrong Python environment:
C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\
You should be running it in
C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User

See
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

and 
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

1. Close your jupyter notebook and terminate ipython.
2. Restart Terminal
3. Enter this command in Terminal:

```html
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

4. Re-run your ipython / Jupyter notebook now. It works like a charm.

Comment: Please elaborate on how step 3 will help the user.

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: This helped... I'd love to understand why, particularly so I could then suggest a more permanent solution.

Comment: In short, this will restart the python / Jupyter notebook , and set the text coding to UTF-8, which may be the cause for many of you, ( my problem was that I forget to restart the notebook after re-install a package )

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install matplotlib --force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find which 'matplotlib.py' is imported and then open that file and check if it has 'cbook' or not.

```
import imp
imp.find_module("matplotlib")
```

Comment: I could see the cbook.py here (C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib) in matplotlib folder.. still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and it was because of this line : 
from sys import stdout
i deleted this import and the problem is gone now

Comment: this can be a comment and not an answer. please, read the rules of this community.