# Attribute Error for mathplot lib cbook

Tags: matplotlib

I am using a python based Tight binding code Pybinding, while importing it I get following error:

```html
>>> import pybinding as pb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .model import *
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/model.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import results
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/results.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import pltutils
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/pltutils.py", line 465, in <module>
    pb_style = _make_style()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/pltutils.py", line 425, in _make_style
    palette = list(get_palette('Set1'))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/pltutils.py", line 327, in get_palette
    palette = cmap(bins)[:, :3]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 485, in __call__
    cbook._putmask(xa, xa == 1.0, almost_one)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '_putmask'
```

I have tried all the troubleshooting procedures posted on here:
[Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236953/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-cbook)

Also install and reinstall matplotlib and pybinding package but it has not solved my issue. I am using fedora 27 as my operating system and output imp.find_module is:

```html
(None, '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib', ('', '', 5))
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am facing this problem while creating a wordcloud