# iPython, Jupyter -> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner at programming and I am working on an online course which uses ipython and jupyter notebook. I am working with Mac OS 10.13.3.

I have tried importing matplotlib as follows,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

However, the following error is being generated.

```
--------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-30-385145dcc870> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

/Users/Varshil/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     27 from cycler import cycler
     28 import matplotlib
---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
     30 from matplotlib import style
     31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

/Users/Varshil/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     34 import matplotlib.collections as collections

/Users/Varshil/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in <module>()
      9 import numpy as np
     10 import matplotlib
---> 11 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     12 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation
     13 from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'
```

It would be of great help if someone could help me solve this issue. I have tried looking up online but have found no successful leads.

Comment: Something went wrong when installing matplotlib. Try to uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236953/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-cbook).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
Initially, I installed the whole package using graph lab create launcher. 

So I uninstalled the graph lab launcher and installed it again.
I checked after uninstallation whether matplotlib exists and it did not.

However the issue still remains.

Comment: I have tried finding which matplotlib has been imported by typing...

`import imp`
`imp.find_module("matplotlib")`

This is the result.

`(None,
 '/Users/Varshil/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib',
 ('', '', 5))`

Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using old version of matplotlib.

Those who are using GraphLab Create, first activate virtual environment:

```
source gl-env/bin/activate
```

Now upgrade matplotlib:

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

Output:

`Found existing installation: matplotlib 1.5.1
Uninstalling matplotlib-1.5.1:
Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-1.5.1
Successfully installed matplotlib-2.1.2`

Restart iPython/Jupyter.

If you are on Mac, you might get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework.`

Create a file ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc there and add the following code: `backend: TkAgg`

Again restart iPython/Jupyter.